# Uipath For Each Row is skipping rows

Tags: foreach, uipath

I have to read a range of two columns and compare them and then do something with them on a third column. That part is covered, however, my range goes from cell A2 to A10 (A1 is part of the range but it's the column header) but it skips rows 6 and 10

I have assigned the range as a variable through the activity read range including cells A1:A10. When I run it, it skipps rows 6 and 10 and in a third column where the comparison should be done, ends up empty. For the rest of rows is working ok.

Comment: What does the input file look like? What have you done so far? Can you share your code?

Comment: Show us the Excel file.